# How to get the logically correct pixel that is tapped in a Swift Chart transformed by `scaleEffect`?

Tags: swiftui

To show a Swift Chart in a `ScrollView` that is scrolled to the right when it appears I'm transforming the chart with `scaleEffect` and then undoing the transform on the ScrollView. However I'm not able to figure out how to get the pixel that the user logically tapped on when I implement an `onTapGesture` in the `chartOverlay`. My example code prints the wrong day.

I also have a hacky solution to that doesnt handle the cases where the chart is smaller than the screen and expands itself, of when Charts adds unpredictable spacing to the left and right of the chart

I would appreciate any help. Thank you

(As an alternative to using scaleEffect I tried to scroll the chart to the right with a `scrollTo` in `onAppear`, but this was buggy, especially on ios16.)

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    var dates = (0..<100).map { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: $0, to: Date())! }

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geo in
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                    HStack(spacing:0) {
                        Chart {
                            ForEach(dates, id:\.self) { date in
                                LineMark(x: .value("day", date),
                                         y: .value("value", 1))
                            }
                        }
                        .chartXAxis {
                            AxisMarks(preset: .extended,
                                      position: .bottom,
                                      values: .stride (by: .day)) { value in
                                let label = value.as(Date.self)!.formatted(.dateTime.day()) + "\n" +
                                    value.as(Date.self)!.formatted(.dateTime.month())
                                AxisValueLabel(collisionResolution: .greedy) {
                                    Text(label)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .frame(minWidth: 40.0*CGFloat(dates.count)+10.0, maxWidth:.infinity, minHeight: geo.size.height, maxHeight:.infinity, alignment: .center)
                        .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1)
                    }
                    .frame(minWidth: geo.size.width, maxWidth:.infinity, maxHeight:.infinity, alignment:.center)
                    .chartOverlay { proxy in
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                                .onTapGesture { location in onTap(at: location, geometry: geometry, proxy: proxy) }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .frame(maxWidth:.infinity, maxHeight:.infinity, alignment:.center)
                .scaleEffect(x: -1, y: 1)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func onTap(at: CGPoint, geometry: GeometryProxy, proxy: ChartProxy) {
        let origin = geometry[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin
        let selectedDate = proxy.value(atX: at.x - origin.x, as: Date.self)
        if selectedDate != nil {
            print("1 tapped on date \(selectedDate)") // this works without the scaleEffects
        }

        let selectedDate2 = proxy.value(atX: (40.0*CGFloat(dates.count)+10.0 - at.x) - origin.x, as: Date.self)
        if selectedDate2 != nil {
            print("2 tapped on date \(selectedDate2)") // this does not work
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized the answer is simple - the `.chartOverlay` modifier must modify the `Chart` earlier than the `.scaleEffect` modifier.